# I'm trying to send messages that are not in a row mysql

Tags: mysql, discord.js

I'm trying to send messages that are not in rows like this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

I would like it to be like this
`1, 2, 3, 4

My code, I'm getting the results from a database, mysql

```
    const Discord = require("discord.js")
    
    
    
    module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args, con) => {
    
        if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
            message.channel.send("You don't have permissions to execute this command.")
        }
    
        if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission(["MANAGE_ROLES", "ADMINISTRATOR"])) {
            return message.reply("I don't have permissions to warn.").then(m => m.delete(5000));
        }
    
        
        var person  = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[1]));
        if(!person) {
            embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("QuackCraft")
            .setColor("#ff0000")
            .setDescription("Invalid Arguments")
            .addField("Please use:", "`-warnings <user>`")
            return message.channel.send(embed)
        }
    
    
    
        con.query(`SELECT * FROM warnings WHERE userid = "${person.id}"`, (err, results) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            if(results.length === 0) {
                message.channel.send("This user has no active warnings!")
            } else {
            
                con.query(`SELECT * FROM warnings WHERE warns != "0"`, (err, results1) => {
                    message.channel.send(`<@${person.id}> has currently ${results1[0].warns} active warnings!`)
                })
    
                con.query(`SELECT * FROM warnings`, (err, rows) => {
                    message.channel.send(`Getting the results from the database!`)
                    rows.forEach(function (row) {  
                        console.log(row.reason); 
                    }) 
                    
                    
                })
            }
    
        
        
            
        })
    
    
    }
    
    module.exports.config = {
        name:"warnings",
        description:"Checks the warns of people people",
        usage:"-warnings <user>",
        aliases: ["warns"]
    }
```

It just sends the warns in a straight line, but I've been trying to figure it out how to send it like
1,2,3,4 and not in a straight line, if you can help me thank you!

Comment: use a GROUP_CONCAT for the numbers in your query  for the ids

Comment: and stop using SELECT * please

Comment: Thanks for helping me, this problem has been fixed!